# Setting uicollectionview cell size to 0

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have collectionview cells that are updated dynamically by long running jobs.

I want to be able to delete cells (representing jobs) from the view but preserve relationship between the long running job and the original index path which should display that jobs results.

I've tried using

```
self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.dataSource collectionview:self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:@[path]];
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[path]];
        }  completion:nil];
```

but i am having problems updating all the relationships to the new index paths that the jobs should relate to.

I have also tried assigning cells an identifier to a job and looking up the cell with the jobs identifer, but this approach doesn't work as the cell for the job can change when scrolling.

I think it would be easiest to set the size of the collectionview cell to 0 in the delegate method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but was not able to set the size to zero

Any way around this.